# Ubuntu doesn't release caps lock

Tags: linux, ubuntu, capslock

I usally use the Caps Lock to write the first capital letter of a word, and it happens that when i release it, ubuntu waits before effectively releasing the caps lock.

i.e. if on the keyboard i press

<kbd>CAPS-LOCK</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>CAPS-LOCK</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>

It should print

```
Mery
```

but in fact i get

```
MEry
```

Now i have to activate the caps lock, press *M*, de-activate the caps lock, wait about a second an then finish writing the word.

Is there a way to solve it?

---

**UPDATE**

> It's strange, I think that keyboards send signals which are actually the ASCII code for symbols or instructions. So, there must be a way how the OS takes and manages this signal. Ok, they're processor interruptions at last but I don't think interruptions are the *matter* here. You should edit your question and give info about Ubuntu version, either 32 or 64 bits, graphical interface and probably keyboard brand. Check about any keyboad driver?

I'm having this problem with keyboard since Ubuntu 10.04, i'm currently running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64, keyboard brand is logitech for the USB keyboard, but i have the same problem with the laptop integrated keyboard (it is an Asus A55VM)

Comment: I think it's odd, are you sure your keyboard is not stuck?

Comment: @Diego Yes, i tried with every PC i have at home, with live ubuntu and also installed ubuntu, i also bought a new keyboard because i thought that my previous one was the problem, but it wasn't. I have this problem since Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: It's strange, I think that keyboards send *signals* which are actually the ASCII code for symbols or instructions. 

So, there must be a way how the OS takes and manages this signal. Ok, they're processor interruptions at last but I don't think interruptions are the *matter* here.

You should edit your question and give info about Ubuntu version, either 32 or 64 bits, graphical interface and probably keyboard brand.

Check about any keyboad driver?

Comment: @Diego ok, check my edit

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a quite interesting problem, despite my first notion to "just use the shift key" you, I think that's not an option. After all Linux is mostly about customizing the experience, so that must be part of it.

Enough chatter, let's cut to the chase. This bug has [already been reported as #27903 back in 2010](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27903) (and marked as RESOLVED FIXED in September 2012) on the [freedesktop.org bug tracker](https://bugs.freedesktop.org). I'll now quote some comments from that bug report to spare you some of the back and forth:

> Burak Çalık 2010-04-29 15:12:36 UTC
>
> The problem occurs if you are used to typing capital letters using capslock button instead of shift and if you are writing too fast.
>
> For example, you can see the same sentences which were written in windows and linux;
>
> In Windows:
>   "Hello friends. How are you today?"
>
> In Linux:
>   "HEllo friends. HOw are you today?"
>
> While you are writing, capslock sticks opened on Linux.
>
> ---
>
> Andreas Wettstein 2011-08-07 01:14:52 UTC
>
> Created attachment 50006 [details] [review] Support noLock and
>   noUnlock in xkbcomp
>
> This patch to xkbcomp allows to specify the noLock and noUnlock flag
>   in a more natural syntax.  Instead of the Private action shown before,
>   one now can write "LockMods(modifiers=Shift+Lock,affect=unlock)".
>
> ---
>
> Peter Hutterer 2011-08-10 23:47:42 UTC
>
> (In reply to comment #26)
>
> > Created an attachment (id=49973) [details]
> >     noLock and noUnlock in _XkbFilterLockState
>
> forwarded to the list thanks.
>   http://patchwork.freedesktop.org/patch/6691/
>
> ---
>
> Peter Hutterer 2012-03-05 22:15:36 UTC
>
> commit e3f6a76dd480717eae4b17ad8e2ff707de2ffe4c Author: Andreas
>   Wettstein  Date:   Thu Aug 11 16:33:33 2011
>   +1000
>
> ```
> xkb: Support noLock and noUnlock flags for LockMods
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Peter Hutterer 2012-06-17 22:38:56 UTC
>
> (In reply to comment #34)
>
> > I have xorg server 1.12 installed. I believe i just have to define caps lock as
> >     described in comment #27. But i have no idea which file to edit, would you
> >     please help?
>
> ```
> xkbcomp -xkb $DISPLAY my_xkbmap
> then edit my_xkbmap and re-load it as
> xkbcomp my_xkbmap $DISPLAY
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Peter Hutterer 2012-06-18 19:54:25 UTC
>
> (In reply to comment #37)
>
> > Thanks a lot. The caps lock delay problem is gone away now. Is this method
> >     permanent or do i have to load my_xkbmap everytime i start x?
>
> Andreas, can you please file a xkeyboard-config bug to get this
>   snipped introduced by default into the keymap. I think it's useful
>   enough to carry it.
>
> ---
>
> Andreas Wettstein 2012-10-28 13:18:01 UTC
>
> > Andreas, can you please file a xkeyboard-config bug to get this snipped
> >     introduced by default into the keymap. I think it's useful enough to carry
> >     it.
>
> Sorry for wasting another four months.  Now it is there, bug 56491.

So there is a patch floating around which solves one half of the problem. The [referred to bug report #56491](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56491) lives in the same bug tracker, but still carries the status NEW.

From that bug there's nothing to quote, only some back and forth between developers on why and how to fix it.

So yes, this problem still persists, but people are working on it. There are further instructions, debugging information and workarounds in the bug #27903 apart from what I quoted. There is also a patch-set in #56491 which is supposed to fix this bug (but as said, they're discussing that).

Comment: Does this bug still exist?

Comment: @Hashim I did a quick test and couldn't reproduce it on my Ubuntu 16.04. So I guess no.

Comment: See below, the thread owner still seems to experience it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and very effective solution to this problem is posted [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1462333.html).

> ```
> xkbcomp -xkb $DISPLAY /home/username/myxkbmap
> ```
>
> Now you'll have a file named *myxkbmap* in your home directory. Open
>   that file with your text editor and edit the key <caps> entry
>   like this:
>
> ```
> key <CAPS> { repeat=no, type[group1]="ALPHABETIC", symbols[group1]=[ Caps_Lock, Caps_Lock ], actions[group1]=[
> ```
>
> LockMods(modifiers=Lock),
>   Private(type=3,data[0]=1,data[1]=3,data[2]=3) ] };
>        Save it. Then reload it:
>
> ```
> xkbcomp /home/username/myxkbmap "$DISPLAY"
> ```
>
> You can write an executable startup script so that you won't have to
>   do this every time X starts, like this:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> xkbcomp /home/username/myxkbmap "$DISPLAY"
> ```
>
> Save this with any name you want, make it executable, and make it one
>   of your startup programs.

Comment: Are you sure this is still a problem? Are you telling me a bug from 2010 still hasn't been resolved?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this is not working for me, I tried it not long ago because I was still searching for a solution to this but it didn't work on my Ubuntu 18.04 system.

Comment: @Hashim It was never solved for me. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 now and the bug still exists. In my case, the issue is that caps lock state changes on key release, while all other keys change their state on key press. Sometimes I happen to write too fast, and it happens that I: `press CL` - `release CL` - `press A` - `press CL` - `press B` - `release CL`. It happens that the resulting string is `AB` instead of `Ab`, because caps lock gets deactivated on key release instead of key press (so, after `B` has been pressed). Other keys react on key press instead of key release.